# How Does MATLAB Optimization Functions Work without Jacobian or Hessian?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, matlab, numerical-optimization, finite-differences

How does MATLAB optimization tools works?

They just get the error function and doesn't require Jacobian (First derivatives) or Hessian (Second derivatives)?

How is it possible?

Comment: I upvoted this because it's not a "how do I use Matlab?" question and the answer may involve interesting mathematics.  In addition, the Mathworks own doc pages don't always describe what algorithms they use.

Comment: You can always use finite differences to approximate the gradient. You can do the same for the Hessian, or accumulate information to build a passable approximation (for example, quasi-Newton, BFGS, etc).

Comment: It is possible, however, is that the case in Matlab? How it determines the finite difference value (dx)?

Comment: If you look in "Numerical Recipes in C" or a similar book, they describe algorithms that optimize without knowing the Jacobian.

Comment: This _might_ be a good question for Computational Science Stack Exchange.  Someone there certainly knows the answer.  I say _might_ because most questions there are more difficult and not specifically about how Matlab works.  I'd consult their FAQ first.

Comment: You can find out easily by provide a function that prints out its arguments when called.

Answer (score 1):

Since, given the function and assuming it is differential, one could use numerical methods to approximate the Gradient and the Hessian of a function at a given point.

One method doing so is the [Finite Differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) method.
The problem with this kind of method is that for high dimension problems those methods require high amount of calculation of the objective function at the given point (For the Gradient, at least $ n $ times for a function in dimension $ n $).

There are methods to ease this calculations as done in the Quasi Newton Method, yet still it is not negligible.

Hence, if you have the analytic function for the Gradient and the Hessian it is better to supply them to MATLAB.